# This script included in a package has some error leading to one variable having context different from others

Tags: packages, contexts

The package modt

```
BeginPackage["modt`"];   
SIRsh;
Begin["`Private`"];
SIRsh=Module[{S,Vg,var}, var= {s, i, v};
    S={{\[Mu] N,-\[Beta]/Nv,0,      -\[Mu],0,0},
       {0,  \[Beta]/Nv,0,       0,-\[Mu]i,0},
       {0,  0,  -\[Beta]v/N,   0,\[Beta]v Nv/N,-\[Nu]}};
    Vg={1,g[s,v],h[i,v], s  ,i , v }; 
    {S,Vg}
    ];
End[];
EndPackage[];
$ContextPath = DeleteDuplicates[Append
[$ContextPath, "modt`Private`"
    ]]
```

includes a script which introduces in `var= {s, i, v}` three local variables s,i,v. For some reason, v is interpreted differently from s,i and later when I call it

```
<<modt.wl;
    Vg=SIRsh[[2]]
    var={s,i,v}
```

I get warning messages
like `Global`v::shdw: Symbol v appears in multiple contexts {Global`,mods`Private`};` or `g[s, modt`Private`v]` which warn me about v, but not about s,i.
What could be the difference?

Comment: Works for me. Start a new kernel and try again.

Comment: I restarted (5 times) but still I got {1, g[s, modt`Private`v], h[i, modt`Private`v], s, i, modt`Private`v}, and v is in red. To be sure, I quit Mathematica. Still,  v is seen differently than s,i on my 13.3

Comment: I have 14.0. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: At least it works almost fine if I take the script out of the package and add it where I use it. v is still in red (with no error message!), but the results are fine

Comment: Glad to hear this. :)